# Wired net not working after upgrading to ubuntu 13.04

Tags: internet, wired

Yesterday I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 from 12.10 on my DELL latitude D520 laptop, but then my cable internet stopped working. Its working with live CD but when installed, it doesn't work.

```
simarjit@simar-lapi:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7001 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:573938 (573.9 KB)  TX bytes:573938 (573.9 KB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:115.241.157.174  P-t-P:220.224.141.129  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1121 errors:24 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1146 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:969495 (969.4 KB)  TX bytes:111813 (111.8 KB)
```

Comment: Arent you able to browse the internet?

Comment: Yes, I am connected through my Reliance Data card.

Comment: But, I want to connect through wired connection.

Comment: The above output of ifconfig was captured when your lan cable was connected?

Comment: Following is the output with Lan connected

Comment: simarjit@simar-lapi:~$ ifconfig
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:7121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7121 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:591690 (591.6 KB)  TX bytes:591690 (591.6 KB)

Comment: ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
          inet addr:115.241.157.174  P-t-P:220.224.141.129  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2675 errors:60 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3118 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
          RX bytes:1754051 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:380789 (380.7 KB)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have Toshiba Portege. Surprisingly in my case I found that it starts working when the power chord is connected. After getting the connection I can remove the power chord. But after rebooting same has to done.